# How to remove the click event from an anchor link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been doing some research into this and so far, all I've been able to find it that you can only remove the event listener. Not the actual event. For example, I have an anchor link which after being clicked once. I wouldn't like the user to be able to click it again. How can I go about doing this?

I have a very simple set up below:

```
      <script>

            $(document).on('click', '.prevPage', function () {
    alert("In");
    if (parseInt($('.nextPage').attr('rel')) > 2) {
        //TAKE OFF CLICK    
        currentPage -= 1;
        rowsShown = $('.pageSize').val();
        skip = (currentPage * rowsShown) - rowsShown;
        GetMoreData(skip, 2);
    }
});

function RePager(skip, btnClicked) {
    /* ** NEED TO WORK OUT THE INPUT BOX ** */
    if (ReportType() == 2) {
        var FilteredData = $('.BoolFiltered').val();
        var totalPages = GetTotalPages();
        if (totalPages == 0) {
            totalPages = 1;
        }
        var newPrevPage = currentPage - 1;
        var newNextPage = currentPage + 1;
        /*
        1 - First Page 
        2 - Prev Page
        3 - Next Page
        4 - Last Page
        4+ - Ajax filter
        */
        switch (btnClicked) {
            case 1:
                $('.prevPage').attr('rel', 1);
                $('.nextPage').attr('rel', 2);
                $('.lastPage').attr('rel', totalPages);
                $('.pagedisplay').val(currentPage + '/' + totalPages);
                break;
            case 2:
                $('.prevPage').attr('rel', newPrevPage);
                $('.nextPage').attr('rel', newNextPage);
                $('.lastPage').attr('rel', totalPages);
                $('.pagedisplay').val(currentPage + '/' + totalPages);
                //PUT CLICK BACK ON
                break;
            case 3:
                $('.prevPage').attr('rel', newPrevPage);
                $('.nextPage').attr('rel', newNextPage);
                $('.lastPage').attr('rel', totalPages);
                $('.pagedisplay').val(currentPage + '/' + totalPages);
                break;
            case 4:
                $('.prevPage').attr('rel', totalPages - 1);
                $('.nextPage').attr('rel', totalPages);
                $('.lastPage').attr('rel', totalPages);
                $('.pagedisplay').val(totalPages + '/' + totalPages);
                break;
            default:
                currentPage = 1;
                $('.prevPage').attr('rel', 1);
                $('.nextPage').attr('rel', 2);
                $('.lastPage').attr('rel', totalPages);
                $('.pagedisplay').val(currentPage + '/' + totalPages);

        }

    }
}


        </script>

<body>
    <a class="prevPage">WORK</a>
</body>
```

Edit: I will go into more specifics. After the user has clicked on the event, I would like to disable the click. After the function has ended, I would then like to allow the user to click the button again. I could always just change the class name but I don't want to do this, I'd rather find a more elegant solution.

EDIT 2: Check above code for actual issue

Comment: You can simply turn off the `click` event like `$(".test").off('click', function (e) {} );`

Comment: `After the function has ended` Which function are you talking about? If you are doing any async operation, then provide relevant code

Comment: @A.Wolff Check edit for actual code.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn So `GetMoreData()` is doing ajax request? You provided `RePager()` code which seems unrelevant here

Comment: @A.Wolff It's not, it's just the GetMoreData function is < 200 lines so I didn't paste it. At the end of the ajax request I call RePager()

Comment: So in `RePager()`, remove class `.disabled` if using code i provided in @wjvander answer, delegating click event (checking for `.prevPage:not(.disabled)` selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest would be to use CSS instead of trying to remove listeners and what-not.

jQuery has a [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function that you can use.

Example CSS

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Then your script code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".test").click(function () {
     $(this).addClass("disabled");
   });
});
```

That way you can easily do [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) as well

Comment: Ya removing class when any async op completes. But you should delegate it: `$(document).on('click', '.prevPage:not(.disabled)', function () {...});`

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.prevPage:not(.disabled)', function () {$(this).addClass("disabled"); doSomeAsyncRequest().always(function(){$(this).removeClass('disabled');}.bind(this));`

Comment: Good solution, but I didn't want to do this using css +1

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Reason for that? Because this would be better imho than binding/unbinding event. BTW, you don't need to use `pointer-events: none;` if you are delegating event and you could still customize style for disabled anchor.

Comment: @A.Wolff I've implemented this solution instead. The others were extra lines of code instead of just adding/removing a class. My mind has been changed and I believe that this is the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.one()` instead:

```js
$(document).one('click', '.test', function(e) {
  $('pre').append(e.type+'ed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test">WORK</a>
<br>
<pre></pre>
```

---

As per your edits:

You can use `.on()` to bind the event and use `.off()` to unbind it. something like this:

```js
function bindClick(e) {
  $('pre').append(e.type + 'ed');
  $(document).off('click', '.test', bindClick); // unbound click
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.test', bindClick); // bound again after 2 sec
  }, 2000);
}

$(document).on('click', '.test', bindClick); // bound click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test">WORK</a>
<br>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Okay then it wasn't in the question so for this `.off()` can be used with `.on()` event listener.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap it in dom ready initially. Otherwise the script will run before the element is getting ready on the dom. Then you can use `event.preventDefault()` to disable the normal click.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".test").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```

Comment: I dont think this is what SO is asking about.

Comment: 'After the function has ended' .Which function?

Comment: The on click function

Comment: @AndrewKilburn But `alert()` is modal, so what?

Comment: Delegating to `document` level as in OP's code, you don't need to wait for DOM to be ready

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, you are correct. Didnt think about that at that time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).off("click");
});
```

Use `.off`

```
$(document).off('click', '.test');
```